In Python, Docplex reports BrokenPipeError and Invalid argument when solving a particularly large cp model
The model is solved fine, but when the model is relatively large (150,000 variables, 620,600 constraints), cp.solve() reports an error
 "0SError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" in self.pout.write(frame) in the _write_message(self, cid, data=None) method.

Also there will be an error "BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe"
1.error code location
2. error msg
This problem probably occurred while constructing the solver model，Small models will not be a problem.
